# Getting value of all fields of objects in a loop

Tags: kotlin

I have class with 12 fields. Is there any way in kotlin to get values of all of them in a loop? I know I can get lists of all fields in a class but I don't know if I can read values from it.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Might it be better to store the values in a `Map` instead of separate properties?  Or is there some other alternative?  (While reflection is the direct answer to this, as @Rene demonstrates, I wouldn't recommend it: it's slow, unsafe, fragile, and ugly.  It's useful for frameworks, plug-ins, build tools, and the like, but rarely a good fit for production code.)

Comment: @gidds I have sqlite database with 12 columns, can't really change it, not my decision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection `MyClass::class.memberProperties` to get all properties. Each property has a method `get` to extract the value from a suitable object:

```
val myObject = MyClass(...)
for (prop in MyClass::class.memberProperties) {
    println(prop.get(myObject))
}
```